# Get-ItemProperty inside a loop

Tags: powershell

I have a collection of type `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` Example:

```
$arr = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

The 3rd element contains the property I am interested in. I access it using:

```
$arr[3] | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "MyProgram*"}
```

This works fine. Now I am trying to loop over the collection (index number is not known):

```
$arr | ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $_ | Where-Object {$_.DisplayNAme -like "MyProgram*"}
```

Returns the error: "Cannot find path because it does not exist".

How can I display the same output as `$arr[3] | ...` using a loop?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The third element would be at position 2, because PowerShell is zero-based, meaning the index starts at 0. Since the paths of those keys are under the HKLM hive, if you do a ` Set-Location HKLM:\ ` before running your loop, you should be able to get to the data you're after

Comment: Change `Get-ItemProperty $_` to `$_ |Get-ItemProperty` or `Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to search for it?

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Where-Object {$_.Displayname -like 'MyProgram*'}
```